# show colors and disable line wrap

Tags: less

Using the `less` paginator, you can use the `-r` option to properly display colored input and the `-S` option to disable line wrap.

However, when using `less -rS` or equivalently `less -r -S`, colors are diplayed but lines are wrapped. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Specifying `-R` instead of `-r` might work for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the `-r` option doesn't work, maybe the `-R` option will do what you want:

> -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
>
> Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly in most  cases.   ANSI  "color"  escape
>                 sequences are sequences of the form:
>
> ESC [ ... m
>
> where  the  "..." is zero or more color specification characters For the purpose of keeping track of screen appearance, ANSI color escape sequences are assumed to not move
>                 the cursor.  You can make less think that characters other than "m" can end ANSI color escape sequences by setting the environment variable LESSANSIENDCHARS to the list of
>                 characters which can end a color escape sequence.  And you can make less think that characters other than the standard ones may appear between the ESC and the m by setting
>                 the environment variable LESSANSIMIDCHARS to the list of characters which can appear.

Comment: Thank you! Actually this was meant to be a self-answered question (after a while I figured this out and wanted to share), but I've got too few reputation and -after letting me write the answer- it said I should wait 8 hours before posting... Never mind, my answer looked exately like yours

Comment: As a side-note, this is similar to what `git` does: by default it uses `less` as its pager and invokes it with `LESS=FRSX` in the environment (just like `less -FRSX`)

Comment: @Davide, that's interesting about `git`, I always wondered why it behaved differently, never got around to investigating though. Thanks.